# Highcharts - drawing gridlines only up to the series

Tags: highcharts

I have an areaspline with only one series. The design calls for drawing x-axis gridlines that touch the series and don't extend beyond that. Is it possible to do this? Here's my code to configure the gridlines:

```
xAxis: {
    gridLineWidth: 1,
    tickAmount: 30,
    lineWidth: 0,
    labels: {
       enabled: false
    },
    minPadding: 0
},
```

Comment: It is not supported as an option. But this question has been asked a lot - do some searching here and you will most likely come up with a few potential solutions.

Comment: Your options are essentially either 1) find a way to hide the gridlines above the series - ie, add a stacked area series with a white fill, or 2) find a way to draw your own lines that run from the axis to the series point. Either via a line/scatter series, or via the chart.renderer() function

Comment: Very creative! Thanks for the summary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another option (other then 2 mentioned by jlbriggs in a comment on the question) might be to [extend Highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/extending-highcharts/extending-highcharts) and change paths of grid lines in a wrapper like:

```
  (function(H) {
    var UNDEFINED;
    H.wrap(H.Tick.prototype, 'render', function(p) {
      p.apply(this, [].slice.call(arguments, 1)); //run original function

      if (this.axis.isXAxis && this.gridLine) {
        var point = this.axis.series[0].options.data[this.pos],
          d = this.gridLine.attr('d').split(' ');
        if (point !== UNDEFINED) {
          d[2] = this.axis.chart.yAxis[0].toPixels(point);
          d = d.join(' ');
        } else {
          d = ''; //remove if not crossing any point
        }
        this.gridLine.attr({
          d: d
        });
      }
    });

  })(Highcharts)
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/69f5z3us/

If a grid line is not crossing any point, then the grid line is removed, but you could change that part of the code if you want to.

Comment: That's awesome! Thanks, @Kacper Madej.